# Why is this method always able to move the top card to a given equation?

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory

Let's say we have a deck of card of 2n, and the position of a card in a deck is k, which means that the card is the k-th card from the top. And we could shuffle the card in two ways: In-shuffle, and Out-shuffle.
For in-shuffle:
$$f(k)=
\begin{cases}
2k,& 0<k\leq n\\
2k-2n-1,& n<k\leq2n
\end{cases}$$

For out-shuffle:
$$f(k)=
\begin{cases}
2k-1,& 0<k\leq n\\
2k-2n,& n<k\leq 2n
\end{cases}$$

Now, if we want to move the original top card to any position m, we could do the following:
We could express m-1 as the sum of distinct powers of 2, then do an in-shuffle for each power of 2 with coefficient 1 and an out-shuffle otherwise.
May I know why is this true, could you please explain to me.  Thank you so much.,

Comment: The positions $2k-2n-1$ and $2k-2n$ will be negative. I think you have $k$ and $n$ backwards.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't think it would be negative, since I have defined that k is bigger than n, so 2k-2n or 2k-2n-1 should not be negative

Comment: Oh, of course. Haven't had my coffee yet!

Answer (score 1):

In order to reach $m$, do the following

- If $m$ is even, first reach $m':=\frac m2$, then apply an in-shuffle
- If $m$ is odd (and $>1$), first reach $m':=\frac{m+1}2$, then apply an out-shuffle.

Since $m'<m$ in all cases, the reachability of $m$ follows by induction (with base case $m=1$ being trivial). The relation to the binary representation of $m-1$ follows because the representation of $m-1$ is the representation of $m'-1$ followed by a $1$ or $0$ depending on which case we are in.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But I still don’t understand why we should express them into sum of distinct powers of 2. What does that mean.